# Using the oven wall outlet to plug in a dryer?

Tags: kitchens, dryer, washer, laundry

Is it possible to use the 240v outlet in your kitchen for the oven to plug a dryer into? (For those of us without washer/dryer hookups) and then vent it out through the kitchen window? Thanks so much!

Comment: What sort of oven do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, but probably not.

#### Electrical

Most electric dryers are designed to be connected to a 30 ampere branch circuit, using a NEMA 14-30 plug. While most electric ranges are designed to work with a 50 ampere branch circuit, using a NEMA 14-50 plug.

Since the two devices likely use different plug configurations, it's not going to be as simple as just plugging the dryer in.  You could probably make up an adapter (or maybe find one for sale), but you'd have to make sure it was made well and used the proper materials.

#### Environmental

The next problem you might encounter, is exhausting the dryer. It sounds simple, just stick the hose in the window and let it go. Unfortunately, the exhaust contains quite a bit of moisture and lint.  So you'll have to be careful where you exhaust to, or you'll end up with some really angry neighbors. You'll also have to be concerned with preventing the exhaust from being sucked right back into your home. Since I'm sure you don't want all that moisture and lint in your home either.